# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer edges property is not set as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have implemented an UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer successfully, and my method gets triggered as it should, but the "edges" property of the gesture recogniser is perpetually set to UIRectEdgeNone despite the correct gesture being recognised with the edges set to UIRectEdgeBottom.

Below is my setup for the recogniser:

```
- (void)setupEdgeRecogniser {

        UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer* r = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpFromBottom:)];
        r.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        r.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        r.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
        r.delegate = self;
        [r setEdges:UIRectEdgeBottom];

}
```

And this is the method that gets executed exactly when I expect:

```
- (void)swipeUpFromBottom:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer*)gestureEvent {

    // fault occurs here!  gestureEvent.edges is always UIRectEdgeNone
    if (gestureEvent.edges == UIRectEdgeBottom) {
        // do some stuff
    }

}
```

It's pretty straight forward, except I need to test the edges property to see which edge was recognised, the sample above only demonstrates the issue.  My actual codebase detects on every edge, and I then need to break that down further.

Obviously I can work around this by triggering different methods, but I'd prefer not to in this instance.

Does anyone know why this property is not set how I would have expected?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, despite the name edges, this must be set to a single edge. So there is no need to check which edge was recognised because swipeUpFromBottom will only be fired when swiping up from the bottom . You can add another UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to the view with edges set to left, named leftRecognizer, if you set the delegate to self, then in the delegate method you can check which direction user swiped by this.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)g
{
   if (g == leftRecognizer) {
     //swiped left.
   } else if (g == r) {
     //swiped down.
   }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I setup individual recognisers, but wanted them all pointing to the same method.  I've worked around the issue by splitting it off as you suggested, it was just a bit superfluous in my mind, but never mind it's done now.

Comment: The property name is `edges` AND there's a `UIRectEdgeAll`. Nothing in Apple's documentation. What gives, Apple?